# Making a linear model where all values fall below the regression line

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I'm trying to write a regression line which is positioned in a way that all data points sit below the line, but it still follows the trend. In essence, I want to model the direction of the top most points. I tried to extract the *n* highest values, but they tend to be too close together, causing lower x values to fall above the line still. It's hard to explain so I included a fig. The red line is what I want. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

[image: what I want]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression

Comment: Data, please. Or data generation code.

Comment: Did you just mean *line* rather than *regression line*? In ordinary linear regression with an intercept the values cannot all lie below the regression line because that would imply that the sum of the residuals is positive contrary to the fact that they always sum to zero. –

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @user2974951, you could indeed use Quantile Regression with a tau of 1 (ie. the 100th percentile).

```
library(quantreg)

rq_fit <- rq(hp ~ disp, data = mtcars, tau = 1)
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$hp)
abline(rq_fit)
```

[[image: 100thPercentile]